# NodeJS Promises - "Then" not called

Tags: node.js

I'm new to NodeJS and after spending a few hours trying to understand how Promises work exactly, what seems to be an easy thing still doesn't work.

I'm trying to make a few calls to a database, and once all of those calls are done, do something else. What I have now is the following code, but none of the then-functions are called.

```
var queries = ['SELECT value FROM tag', 'SELECT url FROM download_link'];
console.log("Starting promises");
var allPromise = Promise.all([queryDatabaseAddToResult(connection, queries[0], result), queryDatabaseAddToResult(connection, queries[1], result)]);
  allPromise.then(
    function(result) {
      console.log("1");  // Does not show up
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("2");  // Does not show up either
    }
  );

function queryDatabaseAddToResult(connection, query, result) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        Promise.reject(err);
      }
      console.log(rows);
      result.tags = JSON.stringify(rows);
      Promise.resolve(result);
   });  
})
```

}

The calls to the database do get made, as logging the rows show up in the log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling the correct `resolve` and `reject` functions. It should be:

```
function queryDatabaseAddToResult(connection, query, result) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log(rows);
        result.tags = JSON.stringify(rows);
        resolve(result);
      }
   });  
})
```

Note that the `resolve` and `reject` calls should **not** be scoped with `Promise.`. And you should have used an `else` to avoid calling `resolve` once you've called `reject`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this:

```
var promise1 = queryDatabaseAddToResult(connection, queries[0], result);
var promise2 = queryDatabaseAddToResult(connection, queries[1],result);
Promise.all([prromise1, promise2]).then(result => {
  console.log(1);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I assumed that you have already defined result and connection variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
return Promise.reject() //no need to add else part
```